# Check if a string exists in an array, if not then add it to the array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, find, addition

In C how do I search if a string is there in an array of strings and if it is not there, then add it to the array of strings.

In my code I get a file path -

```
char *file_path;
```

I need to check if it is already there in an array of strings (array of file_path), if it is there then return else add this file_path to the array of strings.

Can some one help me with this code in C?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.

Comment: I am not able to come up with exact code in C. I have the psuedo code and trying to come up with C code.

Comment: We are not a "do my homework" service!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to C,so I was looking for some pointers. Any help is appreciated.  Regards, Riju

Comment: You should try to get as far as you can with an own solution. For example, you mention an array of strings, but I do not see any in your code example. Also there is no `if` statement. You may put gaps in your code if you have no clue about a specific part.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
    if(strcmp(file_path,array[i])==0) return 0;
}

//if it exits the loop it means that it did not find the string 

array=realloc(array,(dim+1)*sizeof(char*));
strcpy(array[dim],file_path);
```

This should be fine. Please do your research on arrays, strings and functions. I.e strncpy() is actually better than the simpler strcpy(), if you are willing to improve the code. 
Also have a look at functions to manipulate dynamic memory ( Malloc, calloc,realloc...)
I am also assuming that you did declare the array the right way (as a char* array[dim]).
Also you should check return values from the various functions but I'll let you do your research since it looks like you have just started with C programming.

Comment: Always wrong to assign the result of `realloc()` directly to the pointer to the object being reallocated; `realloc()` can return a null pointer in the event of an error, and now you have a memory leak and lost data. Assign to a temporary pointer first, and check for successful reallocation before reassigning `array`.

Comment: @DavidBowling right, actually I specified that the code should be interpreted just as a guideline and that error management was left to who is going to implement the whole thing. I feel like the author of the post isn't quite able to understand c code that well too.